# How can I get saved report for Google Analytics with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I think something like this works:

```
var optArgs = {
'savedReport': 'yV_LzjnnSZ6Ejy02d0cwFQ'
};

var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
  tableId, startDate, endDate,
  'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews', 
  optArgs);
)
```

Is it possible to get a saved report I created in Web UI? If so, how can I specify the custom report?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/report-automation-magic) regarding Google Analytics Report Automation (Magic Script).

> Google Analytics Report Automation (Magic) is an integration that reduces the work required to put Google Analytics data into any Apps Script supported product, such as Google Docs, Sites, or Spreadsheets.

It is also possible to write your own code and develop custom scripts. For example, with the Analytics - Apps Script integration, you can request the total users, sessions, and pageviews over time and put this data into a spreadsheet with just the following code:

> ```
> // Get Data.
> var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
>     tableId,
>     startDate,
>     endDate,
>     'ga:users,ga:sessions,ga:pageviews',
>     {'dimensions': 'ga:date'});
>
> // Output to spreadsheet.
> var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet();
> sheet.getRange(2, 1, results.getRows().length, headerNames.length).setValues(results.getRows());
>
> // Make Sandwich.
> ```

To get started now, read our [Automated Access to Google Analytics Data in Google Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script) tutorial. Also check out the [Google Analytics Apps Script reference docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_analytics).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The page you refered shows 2 solutions 1) Google Analytics Report Automation. 2) Write your own code.
1) is not option for me because I need to manipulate data in Spreadsheet by App Script. 
As for 2), I used the code in the linked page and still I have a question. That's why I posted the question.